# Does this 'recursive definition' in Linear Algebra make sense?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I am unsure if this is actually considered a recursive definition, but it is defining a minimum in terms of itself. I am wondering if it is a typo or something else.

Basically I want to know if it is possible to define a value in the following way: $c = \arg \min_x f(x,c)$. I can't seem to write this function in some other manner, and can't see how I could possibly evaluate it.

The specific sentence from linear algebra that I am having an issue with is:

> The number $m_j$
>   is the smallest exponent $m$ such that $(A − λ_jI)^m$ vanishes on
>   $\ker(A − λ_jI)^{m_j}$

This is from the pdf at the top of page 6: http://www.ctr.maths.lu.se/media11/MATM14/2011MATM14_vt11/jordan_.pdf

I am wondering about the definition form itself, and less so about the actual linear algebra involved.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be the smallest exponent such that $(A - \lambda_j I)^m$ vanishes on the generalized eigenspace of $\lambda_j$.

That generalized eigenspace consists of vectors $v$ with the property that $(A - \lambda_j I)^k v = 0$ for **some** $k>0$.

Now you might imagine that as you increase $k$, more and more vectors get sent to $0$ by $T_k(u) = (A - \lambda_i I)^k u$, but the fact is that at some point, no more vectors are sent to $0$. That uppermost "interesting" value of $k$ is called $m_j$.

Frankly, the definition as given makes almost no sense to me, since the vanishing condition appears to hold for all possible positive values $m$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the definition I quoted basically nonsense or is there some kind of valid mathematical interpretation to it? I was also thinking that the last part of the definition should be changed to the generalized eigenspace, but I see this kind of '$m_j$ defined in terms of $m_j$' a couple of times in the pdf, so I was wondering if there's just a gap in my understanding of how to read/evaluate the definition properly, or if the author didn't define things properly

Answer (score 0):

If I read this right, that is not the definition of $m_j$ but rather a fact about it. I would say it is defined als the multiplicity of the $j$-th zero of the characteristic polynomial.